# where is the ublas::vector push_back?

Tags: c++, boost, vector, initialization, ublas

hi may i know where is the ublass::vector push_back or what ever does the same ?

p.s (i'm not talking about std::vector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I can tell from reading the documentation there isn't one, the ublas::vector cannot be expanded. You must initialize it like this:

```
vector<double> v (3);
for (int i = 0; i < v.size (); ++i)
  v (i) = i;
```

Comment: if there is no that means i'll have to use assign(vector) which is stupid , or resize then insert ! extra stupid , hope someone give us a hint